# How to get the attribute value which is defined in model using gson

Tags: android, json, gson

Hi I am using `gson` library in my demo android project. I created a model class & parse `json` response using `gson` library but I want to get the value of attribute which I defined in model class like email, phoneNumber etc.

Login.java

```
public class Login {

    public String email;

    public String phoneNumber;

    public String userID;

    public String twitterHandle;

    public String city;

    public String teams;

    public String follows;

    @SerializedName("username")
    public String userName;

    public String state;

    public String county;

}
```

Parsing `JSON` like below

```
// parse the JSON using GSON library
Gson gson = new Gson();
Login login = gson.fromJson(new String(responseBody), Login.class);
```

When I try to get the value like below login.getEmail then it gives red line no method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a normal error because your `Login` class doesn't have `getEmail` method.

You can create getter methods of the fields and use that getters to get values.

Or you can directly get the values because your field definitions are public.

```
login.email
```